# How to map or associate HTTP request to db call in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, v8

I have a node application with a MySQL database. I want to correlate or map each and every HTTP request to MySQL db calls. 
i.e. the Requirement is to somehow pass on the HTTP-request identification to the consequent async db-call (the next async call is in a new context altogether).

Please give me some suggestions on this.

Comment: means you need to access db on http request calls?

Comment: @SasiKumarM, No you are wrong. I want to associate http request to mysql db call

Comment: I am facing similar kind of issue.

Comment: You want to store every http request inside the database?

Comment: @OscarR, No, I want to know the association of http request to db calls. For example.. If there are 1000 http request causes 1000 db calls then I want to map uniquely each and every request to its respective call. So I want something like a Id that is present in http request which does carried out through its life time.

Comment: Are you sure that each http request corresponds to one db call ?

Comment: @DimitarTsonev, Yes, for my application each http request corresponds to one db call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of research I found that in node.js **async_hooks** module provides an API to register callbacks tracking the lifetime of asynchronous resources created inside a Node.js application.

```
const async_hooks = require('async_hooks');
const eid = async_hooks.executionAsyncId(); // Return the ID of the current execution context.
const tid = async_hooks.triggerAsyncId(); // Return the ID of the handle responsible for triggering the callback of the current execution scope to call.
```